# c++ std::map shared_pointer<std::string> as key and std::map find function with deference

Tags: stl

Hello I have trouble on making my mind on container designing for my game project.

The situation is this:

I have a object class , which contain a ID as data member, which is the filename of the object and using `std::string`. My object data info is loading from `JSON` file and I use the filename as ID. 2 reason is unique and later on I need display the object name at my own editor.

However, in editor I need some additional info for the object, like a `bool` variable to determine which object is being selected.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8ZLn.png)

for this I think of using the string of `nameID` key for `std::map` in editor and the string will be `shared_pointer` as the value will change if the id name been edit

```
std::map<shared_ptr<std::string (ID)>, ObjectEditorInfo>
```

This what I want to be able to do, 
`map_container.find_with_deference("i want to find you");`

The problem is if my key is shared pointer, I want to actually compare it with pointer's value result instead of address.

Any suggest to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want modifiable keys in your map, and thus key identity define a node rather than key content, then search by content is can't-be-helped-but linear:

```
auto element = std::find_if(map.begin(), map.end(), [&key](auto const &node){ return *node.first == key; });
```

Of course strings can be non-unique. You'll need current iterator to search for the next entry:

```
auto next_element = std::find_if(element, map.end(), [&key](auto const &node){ return *node.first == key; });
```